# How to create named soft links in a makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu

I'm exploring ways to improve code module integration and have found interest in using named soft links as opposed to include directories, mainly because that allows the integrator to set a directory name of any imported module to something guaranteed not to collide with the module built or any of its imported modules, as well as keeping imported modules from accidently intercepting eachother. However I'm not sure how to actually accomplish this in a makefile.

Here is the directory hierarchy and expected links:

```
+---proj1
|   +---inc
|   |       head.h
|   |
|   \---src
|           code.c
|
+---proj2
|   +---inc
|   |       head.h
|   |
|   \---src
|           code.c
|
\---proj3
    |   Makefile
    |
    \---src
        |   code.c        
        |   head.h
        |
        +---A                  --> ../../proj1/inc
        |       head.h
        |
        \---B                  --> ../../proj2/inc
                head.h
```

In proj3/src/code.c i would have:

```
#include "head.h"
#include "A/head.h"
#include "B/head.h"
```

I think I need some way to run `ln -s` for each {directory,name} tuple prior to compiling the source, putting the link in the same directory as the source being compiled. Parsing `INC=dir1 dir2` is simple enough, but how to represent and run `ln -s` for each pair/tuple in such a list? Or, if having a whole command in each element (`ln -s dir1 localname`), how to exec all of them?

Other suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do you use GNU make?

Comment: Can you concretize a bit, what symlinks exactly should be created?

Comment: @uzsolt Yes, added tag.

Comment: @tripleee Done.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
linkdirs := A B
dir_A := ../proj1/src
dir_B := ../proj2/src

.PHONY: all symlinks
all: symlinks hello
symlinks:
    $(eval $(patsubst %,ln -fs $$(dir_%) % &&,$(linkdirs)) true
```

Comment: Untested, please ping if there are typos etc

Comment: I don't have a build env available at the moment but the overall concept looks legit.